# Can scripts execute virus on its own if we only open it in an IDE or Notepad?

Tags: malware, virus

If you download scripts such as file with extension such as .py, .java, .cs, .cpp, etc and if you don't run it but only open it in an IDE or notepad then will the virus get executed or is this possible for me to get infected just by doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a vulnerability in the IDE or text viewer that the file is designed to exploit, then certainly.

But that's a different kind of malware that you would get if the file was an executable that infected you when you ran it.

Answer (score 0):

With notepad it shouldn't, that's not certain. Like wise with an IDE, you could accidently click an execute/run button in an IDE.

If you want to look into the contents of a code file that may potentially be a virus, use a good sandbox, or a virtual machine, better yet a vm preferably without any network protocals.