# Can PHP files be dangerous without executing them?

Tags: php

Recently I had a job interview online as a developer and I had to download a .PHP file from an FTP. I used a VPN to connect to it and after downloading the file I just opened it in VS Code to see the code. Since I don't even have PHP installed on my computer to execute it, is there any chance that the file could be infected with something?

Comment: I can be short about this, the answer is no. While the code may contain malicious content, since you can't execute it, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can scripts execute virus on its own if we only open it in an IDE or Notepad?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245563/can-scripts-execute-virus-on-its-own-if-we-only-open-it-in-an-ide-or-notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, the file *could* contain some (non-PHP) code that targets a vulnerability in the IDE you used to open the file (VSCode). This would require an exploitable vulnerability in the IDE itself though, and will probably be extremely obvious to anyone not using this specific IDE. This will make it **extremely unlikely** the file is dangerous.

As far as the actual PHP code goes, it can't do anything as long as it's not run by a PHP interpreter.